# Segmentation fault using fscanf-not allocate memory issue

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I m trying to make this code in order to read greek  letters from a file and print the English letters who sound the same using fscanf. The problem is I keep getting segmentation fault. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{            
    char s[100];    
    int i;
    FILE * myfile;

    myfile = fopen("/home/angelos/Downloads/λεξικο2.txt", "r");

    while( fscanf(myfile, "%s", s) == 1)
        {   
            for (i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
                { 
                    if ( s[i] == 'Α' )
                        { printf("A") ; }
                    else
                     if ( s[i] == 'Β' )
                        { printf("V") ; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: `fscanf(myfile, "%s", s)` --> `fscanf(myfile, "%99s", s)` to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: Do not access pass the data read.  `for (i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)` --> `for (i=0 ; s[i]; i++)`.  Need to see what input was used to diagnose the segmentation fault.  Also test if `myfile == NULL`.

Comment: Check return value of `fopen`.

Comment: Still segmentation fault unfortunately to all these solutions. The file is just a simple txt file containing 4 words

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 serious issues with your code.

1) You never check whether `fopen` is successful.

2) You may read uninitialized signed data.

3) You may overflow your input buffer

All three things may cause your program to fail.

Try these changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{            
    char s[100];    
    int i;
    FILE * myfile;

    myfile = fopen("/home/angelos/Downloads/λεξικο2.txt", "r");

    // Check that fopen went fine
    if (!myfile)
    {
         printf("Failed to open file\n");
         return 1;
    }

    while( fscanf(myfile, "%99s", s) == 1)
                         // ^^
                         // Never read more than 99 chars (i.e. 99 + a terminating null byte)
        {   
            for (i=0 ; i<strlen(s) ; i++)
                      // ^^^^^^
                      // Only iterate over the valid chars
                { 
                    if ( s[i] == 'Α' )
                        { printf("A") ; }
                    else
                     if ( s[i] == 'Β' )
                        { printf("V") ; }
        }
}
```

Comment: I try this exact code. First it didn't recognize strlen(s) and when I replace it with what I had from the beginning I got segmentation fault

Comment: oh you are right.. however just tried it still segmentation fault

Comment: UPDATE: I have forgotten to write a line It does return failed to open file. So what should I do?

Comment: @AngelosSouleles - well first of all make sure that the file really exists in the location used. I can see the file name contains greek letters. I'm not sure that is a problem but you can try to rename the file to something like `a.txt` (and update the program likewise).

Comment: yeah I found it using errno code the renaming worked. Thank you very much for your precious help!